# Category does not exists in rows solution

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I have an export of like 1.3k products.. so I selected only the first two from it.

I go to, System > Import / Export > Import ( Products , Append Complex Data ) just to check the file, uploading this file, `imp1.csv` containing the following:

```
sku,_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,_root_category,_category,name,size,price,special_price,description,short_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,status,visibility,tax_class_id,qty
"3108831022134","simple","Default","base",2,165,"Garnitura oala sub presiune","","132.00","","Garnitura din cauciuc pentru oala sub presiune. Daca vechea dumneavoastra garnitura pentru oala sub presiune s-a stricat, inlocuiti-o cu una noua si folositi din nou oala. Potrivita pentru oale de 4, 6, 8 si 10 litri.","","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","1","4","4","10"
"3367305120848","simple","Default","base",2,165,"Oala fonta aluminiu 24 cm","0-10 l","305.00","","Oala cu capac din sticla, realizata dintr-un aliaj de fonta si aluminiu. Interiorul este perfect finisat. Manerele sunt din bachelita de culoare neagra. Se preteaza tuturor tipurilor de plite, inclusiv cea cu inductie. Diametru: 24 cm.","","/120848 oala fonta aluminiu 24cm GERS _1.jpg","/120848 oala fonta aluminiu 24cm GERS _1.jpg","/120848 oala fonta aluminiu 24cm GERS _1.jpg","0","4","4","10"
```

And then, this happens:

[image]

I have checked the category ID's ( currently 165 ) and it exists:

[image]

What can I do.. I have changed and even removed the `_root_category` from "Frarom" ( originally "Default" ) to its ID, `2`.

I have no idea what to do.. I have tried other answers here but it was a matter of quotes.. what is to be done here ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of scratching my head, I've finally realised that Magento `Import/Export` is different from `Dataflow Profiles`.

If you export your products via those two, you'll notice a big difference. The error is caused due to `Import/Export` not allowing `categoryIDs` and requires full category name paths instead, so there would be attribute `_root_category` and attribute `_category` which needs to be filled.

After that is done, you'll need a valid `status` value ( 1 for `Enabled` and 2 for `Disabled` ). Thats how `Import/Export` works.

On the other hand, `Dataflow > Import All Products` supports attribute `category_ids` which allows you to use only the category ID where you want your product to be placed in. Also, the `status` value will need to be `Enabled` or `Disabled` in `Dataflow`.

So, after everything, my CSV structure went from this:

```
sku,_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,_root_category,_category,name,size,price,special_price,description,short_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,status,visibility,tax_class_id,qty
"3108831022134","simple","Default","base",2,165,"Garnitura oala sub presiune","","132.00","","Garnitura din cauciuc pentru oala sub presiune. Daca vechea dumneavoastra garnitura pentru oala sub presiune s-a stricat, inlocuiti-o cu una noua si folositi din nou oala. Potrivita pentru oale de 4, 6, 8 si 10 litri.","","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","1","4","4","10"
```

To this:

```
"sku","store","type","attribute_set","websites","category_ids","name","size","price","special_price","description","short_description","image","small_image","thumbnail","status","visibility","tax_class_id","qty"
"3108831022134","english","simple","Default","base","165","Garnitura oala sub presiune","","132.00","","Garnitura din cauciuc pentru oala sub presiune. Daca vechea dumneavoastra garnitura pentru oala sub presiune s-a stricat, inlocuiti-o cu una noua si folositi din nou oala. Potrivita pentru oale de 4, 6, 8 si 10 litri.","","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","/022134 garnitura oala sub presiune sitram_1.jpg","Enabled","4","","10"
```

Everything works fine now :) Hope it helps everyone who bumps into this as I've seen there are quite a few people asking about this.

Cheers !

Comment: Plez mark it as correct if it has helped you.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri , it is my own answer , I cannot accept it untill two days pass. I'll accept it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

In your csv file please use root category name and category name instead of id.

Comment: @brentwpeterson it's the correct answer. The categories *must* be referenced by name, not by id.